# How do I make a logo overlap the navbar in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar in bootstrap, it has a logo image centered in the middle. I would like to have the image be larger and stretch beyond the navbar, but instead the navbar just stretches to fit the logo's size. Like this:
[image: example.]

And here's my code, for the navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
    <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="rounded-circle" height="120" width="120">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What do I need to do to make the logo overlay like I want it to? Huge thanks if anyone can figure this out!

Comment: You will need to use absolute positioning for that logo to take it out of the nav document flow and create that overlap.

Comment: I gave it a class "logo" and then used "position: absolute;" in the CSS but i'm not sure what to do beyond there.

Comment: The nav must be set to position relative, then you'll have to center that absolutely positioned element, tips here: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6nLxwbs8/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it's a mess. On top of that it needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `z-index` to logo, so it will come on top of navbar, Here is a solution

```css
body {
background: url('webb-dark.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
height: auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar {
        height:50px;
    }
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
left: -50%;
z-index:2;

}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TITLE</title> 
  
  
  

 </head>
 <body background="webb-dark.png">
  <!-- Uhh maybe move this to CSS. -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark position-relative">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    >
    <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
        <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="logo" height="120" width="120">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row h-100">
 <!-- "sm-0" makes the main column full width on mobile. may or may not work so please test before leaving it. -->
  <div class="col-3 sm-0 md-0" >  </div>
  <div class="col-6 sm-12 md-12 bg-secondary"> 
   <br/><br/>
   <p class = "text-center">
    Hi. This is a test paragraph to align the text and whatnot. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


   </p>
   </div>
  <div class="col-3 sm-0 md-0">  </div>
</div>
</div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be the use of absolute position in conjunction with manually set `left` value depending on where you want the element to be.

```css
.main-logo {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -60px !important;
}

.navbar-collapse:first-child {
  padding-right: 90px;
}

.navbar-collapse:last-child {
  padding-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="m-0 order-0 order-md-1 position-absolute main-logo">
        <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="rounded-circle" height="120" width="120">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/terryeah/pen/NWqXYOO

Comment: Thanks! Though it seems to center itself fine in the codepen, when I use the same code the logo aligns to the left. Why is this?

Comment: @sburbanacademia if the logo is absolutely positioned and the parent div has 100% of width, giving the logo `left: 50%` has to work. If you can show me a codepen with full HTML and CSS code in it, I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I used your jsfiddle code and brought it back here and repositioned the logo. It's over the menu icon on small screens but you can move either one to suit your design style.

I gave the logo a higher z-index of 2 to put it above the menu and used CSS Tricks trick to left margin 50% and then negative margin that same negative percent but in pixels to center the logo. Used top: 0.

New CSS:

```
.logo {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -50px;
     height: 100px;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
body {
background: url('webb-dark.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
height: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar {
        height:50px;
        padding-top: 0;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
height: 100px;
top: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<html>
 <head>
  <title>TITLE</title> 
  
  
  

 </head>
 <body background="webb-dark.png">
  <!-- Uhh maybe move this to CSS. -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

        <a class="mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120/ccff00" class="logo" height="120" width="120">
        </a>
        
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark position-relative">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    >
    <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row h-100">
 <!-- "sm-0" makes the main column full width on mobile. may or may not work so please test before leaving it. -->
  <div class="col-3 sm-0 md-0" >  </div>
  <div class="col-6 sm-12 md-12 bg-secondary"> 
   <br/><br/>
   <p class = "text-center">
    Hi. This is a test paragraph to align the text and whatnot. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


   </p>
   </div>
  <div class="col-3 sm-0 md-0">  </div>
</div>
</div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```